# System.Xml.XmlException occurs with dotnet test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

Using .NET Core's unit testing functionality and the MSTest Framework and Adapter, I am trying to run this simple unit test:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TESTFull
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

However even with the scaffolded dependencies:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.1.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I get this following error when using the `dotnet test` command:

```
Test run for F:\Onedrive\Uni\2-1\Dev Project 1 - Tools & Practices\RESTFull\TESTFull\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TESTFull.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 44.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.ParsePartialContent(XmlNode parentNode, String innerxmltext, XmlNodeType nt)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadInnerXmlElement(XmlElement node, String innerxmltext)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement.set_InnerXml(String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.XmlUtilities.AppendOrModifyChild(XPathNavigator parentNavigator, String nodeXPath, String nodeName, String innerXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferRunSettingsHelper.UpdateRunConfiguration(XPathNavigator navigator, Architecture effectivePlatform, Framework effectiveFramework, String resultsDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.InferRunSettingsHelper.UpdateRunSettingsWithUserProvidedSwitches(XPathNavigator runSettingsNavigator, Architecture architecture, Framework framework, String resultsDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.Utilities.RunSettingsUtilities.GetEffectiveRunSettings(String runSettings, CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.Utilities.RunSettingsUtilities.GetRunSettings(IRunSettingsProvider runSettingsProvider, CommandLineOptions commandlineOptions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.ExecuteArgumentProcessor(IArgumentProcessor processor, Int32& exitCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Note that this error occurs with an empty `TestMethod1()` and also when using the built in xUnit project template. I am using .NET Core 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this issue either using `MSTest` Or `XUnit`. The possible area to look at would be the `Versions` of `PackageReference` especially `MSTest` and `XUnit`. Look up your version in `Nuget` and verify the version of .net standard it support.

Comment: I've tried using other versions. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your file path.  At present, `dotnet test` cannot handle a file path that has an ampersand (i.e., the `&` character) in it.